# how to retrieve list of objects from firebase real time database in flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, firebase-realtime-database

I have the following list of objects in my Firebase Realtime Database:
[image]

It is an object called Year, which has id and year values.

Here is the year model I built:

```
class YearModel {
  int? id;
  String? year;
  
  YearModel({
    this.id,
    this.year,
  });

  factory YearModel.fromMap(Map<dynamic, dynamic> map) {
    return YearModel(
      id: map['id'] ,
      year: map['year'] ,
    );
  }

  
}
```

I tried in many ways to build a code to retrieve it but didn't work here are some of these tries:

```
await Firebase.initializeApp();
          FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.instance;
          DatabaseReference yearsRef = FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref('years');
          yearsRef.onValue.listen((event) {
            for (final child in event.snapshot.children) {
              log('message');
              final map = child as YearModel;
              years!.add(map);
              log(map.toString());
              }
            }, onError: (error) {
              // Error.
            });
```

---

```
final snapshot = await FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref('years').get();
            

            Map<int?,YearModel> map = (HashMap<int?,YearModel>)snapshot;
            
            map.forEach((key, value) {
              final YearModel year = YearModel.fromMap(value);

              years!.add(year);
            });
```

I need to read the list of years from Firebase to use it further.

Comment: The code you shared looks fine, but doesn't call Firebase in any way yet. Are you asking how to read data from Firebase in Flutter? If so, this is probably the right place to start: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/flutter/read-and-write#read_data, but there are also quite some 3rd party tutorials out there: https://www.google.com/search?q=read+from+firebase+realtime+database+in+flutter.

Comment: thanks for sharing but specifically i am asking for how to retrieve list of objects from firebase real time database in flutter
i added my firebase failed calls in the edit please give a look

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This won't work:

```
for (final child in event.snapshot.children) {
  final map = child as YearModel;
```

The `as` keyword in Flutter doesn't actually convert any data. Instead it merely says: "if `child` is a `YearModel` object already, allow me to use it as a `YearModel` object".

What you'll want to do is actually convert the data from the `DataSnapshot` called `child` into a `YearModel` object. Since you already have a `fromMap` factory method, that should look something like this:

```
yearsRef.onValue.listen((event) {
  for (final child in event.snapshot.children) {
    final map = child.value as Map;
    final yearModel = YearModel.fromMap(map)
  }
  ...
```

Comment: Great i did it there is no errors but still not showing any data when i displayed the data, i can not see it
log(yearModel.year.toString());

Comment: check the image here please as i run it in debugging mode 
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1SYBbbic5qgLA31r6u77R4KNz2VxCz6dt/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Oops, I was missing the `.value` accessor in there. Updated.